# Gitlab CI/CD env var availabel only on master

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

If I push to master, it works perfectly, all environment variables available and I have a successful deploy to Heroku.

**Problem**: If I push to the dev branch, it can't see the environment variables for the deploy.

```
$ dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_DEV_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
invalid option "--api-key="
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Environment settings:

[image: gitlab env config]

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-14
  script:
    - mvn clean package
  tags:
    - docker

test:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-14
  script:
    - mvn test
  tags:
    - docker

deploy_dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: ruby:2.3
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_DEV_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  environment:
    name: prod
    url: https://.....herokuapp.com/
  only:
    - dev
  tags:
    - docker

deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  image: ruby:2.3
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_PROD_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  environment:
    name: prod
    url: https://.....herokuapp.com/
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - docker
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because your Heroku api key variable is set as **protected**.

Protected variables are visible only by protected branches and protected tags. That is why it works for you on master but not on dev.

More information: https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README#protect-a-custom-variable and https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/protected_branches.md

Your options are: either remove protected flag, or introduce another unprotected variable with another api key for your non-protected branches which would be less sensitive.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thanks!